# Jira server migration restoring attachments

Tags: centos, jira

We are migrating / upgrading a Jira server 6.4 off Linux and onto a new EC2 centOS distro (first installed fresh 7.5.1 Jira) and most of it seems to be working.  Except for attachments. I don't see attachments in the new Jira and the attachments heath check has failed.  I followed the guide here : https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/restoring-data-from-an-xml-backup-802592998.html
There's no specific mention of exactly how to restore attachments.  We basically tar'ed the entire attachments folder from within /data and copied it over to within the new data/* location and then rebooted Jira service.  Any idea on how to get attachments working?  I don't see any restore or import function from within Jira for attachments either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I would comment but my score isn't high enough yet. You want to make sure you grab the exact same directory structure and permissions as they had before (unless JIRA is now using a different user to operate as). Usually this is the number one reason JIRA can't find the attachments.

1. To fix this try: Stop jira (service jira stop)
2. Untar your attachments in the jira data dir/attachments folder
3. Fix file owner and group: chown -R jira:atlassian (changing to whatever jira user and group uses)
4. Start jira (service jira start) Look at your log (/var/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira.log usually) and try to
   access an attachment and see what it says